# Cairo dock workspace switcher and weblet dissapear on minimize

Tags: shortcut-keys, cairo-dock, minimize, workspace-switcher

Today I discovered that there is a keyboard shortcut (by default) for minimizing windows in Ubuntu 12.04. The shortcut key is `Ctrl + Alt + 0`. I was trying to minimize windows and suddenly I minimized Cairo dock's `workspace switcher` and `weblet`. I am unable to restore them now! They are not appearing anywhere, neither in Cairo-dock nor in the Unity panel. How can I make them visible again?

I have tried to go through various discussion threads on internet, however nobody seems to have had this exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to restore the `weblet` and `workspace switcher` by switching the `weblet` and `worspace-switcher` OFF and ON again in `cairo-dock` settings. Even though I was unable to unminimize the windows, I was able to restore them by this procedure.